# Print rows as sample containing specific value Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I was trying to print a **sample of rows that contain a specific string** and tried to use the contain function, however my code will not print a list of all rows containing the string, but this, so it seems my logic didn't really work:

[image: output]

```
# pandas setup
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10000

# read file
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/source.csv", index_col=0)

# add search parameters 
new_df = df['text'].str.contains('神').sample(frac=0.005, random_state=12345)

# print search parameters
new_df.to_csv("/Users/output.csv")
```

Also: would there be a way to read multiple csv (or json) in the same format and have a sample from all of them printing rows containing a specific value?

Best

Comment: `df['text'].str.contains('神')` is a Boolean Series containing True/False and then you sample that Series. You probably want to slice the DataFrame with that mask, then sample, so `df[df['text'].str.contains('神')].sample(...)`

Comment: Thank you! @ALollz I tried using it as suggested, however will receive the following error: `---->  new_df = df[df['text'].str.contains('神')].sample(frac=0.005, random_state=12345)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3013         # Do we have a (boolean) 1d indexer?
ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`